# jQuery how to load content when back button is clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I am using jQuery to load page content when a link is clicked,

```
$(document).on('click', 'nav a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    window.history.pushState('', '', url);
    url += " #main_wrapper > *";

    $('#main_wrapper').load(url);

});
```

The problem is when i click on the Back button, URL changes and nothing happens.. How can i load the content again when the back button is clicked?

And how can i stop/cancel existing Load when a new link is clicked?

Thanks.

EDIT:

This is how i implemented this, You can easily modify this to your needs.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {

    $('aside nav a').removeClass('active');
    $('a[href="' + document.location + '"]').addClass('active')

    $('#main_wrapper').load(document.location +" #main_wrapper > *");

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i load the content again when the back button is clicked?

You need to assign event handler to `popstate` event to handle 'Back' button pressing, like described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate). With this handler you can analyze the current history state and augment your page accordingly.

> And how can i stop/cancel existing Load when a new link is clicked?

Unfortunately, you can't do this with `.load`, as it returns the 'originator' jQuery object. But if you transform it into more low-level `$.ajax` call (which `success` function should load the response into the element with `.html()`, you can call `.abort` on the returned jqXHR object.

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm.